# how to console.log in react-simple-chatbot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bots, chatbot

i try to do a bot who works as i want but i would like to implement some features (send mails, popups etc..) but i don't understand how can i console.log any elements .

there is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ChatBot from "react-simple-chatbot";
import props from 'prop-types';

function Sendemail() {

  console.log("test")
}
function CustomChatbot(props) {
  const config = {
    width: "300px",
    height: "400px",
    floating: true
  };

  return <ChatBot steps={steps} {...config} />;
 }
export default CustomChatbot;

const steps = [
  {
     id: "Greet",
     message: "Hello, Welcome to our website",
     trigger: "Ask Name",
  },
  {
     id: "Ask Name",
     message: "Please type your name?",
     trigger: "Waiting user input for name"
  },
  {
     id: "Waiting user input for name",
     user: true,
     trigger: "ask questions"
  },
  {
     id: "ask questions",
     message: "Hi {previousValue}, I am Tony the bot, How can i help you!",
     trigger: "informations"
  },
  {
     id: "informations",
     options: [

                { 
                  value: "Who founded Babycare",
                  label: "Who founded Babycare",
                  trigger: "Who founded"
                },
                {
                  value: "Contact",
                  label: "Contact",
                  trigger: "Contact"
                }
                
              ]
  },
  {
     id: "Who founded",
     message: "ERWAN",
     trigger: "informations"
  },




  {
     id: "Contact",
     message: "Ok, first, enter your adress-mail",
     trigger: "Ask email"
  },
  {
     id: "Ask email",
     user: true,
     trigger: "get-email"
  },

  {
    id: "get-email",
    message: "ok, {previousValue} !! Type your value now, please be fair",
    trigger: "your question"
  },

  // {
  //   id: "your question",
  //   message: "Ok. Now, enter your message to the staff. Please be fair !!",
  //   trigger: "your message"
  // },
  {
    id: "your question",
    user: true,
    trigger: "send mail"
  },

  
  {
    id: "send mail",
    message: "ok,  there is your message : {previousValue} !! The support team will answer you as possible",
    
    trigger: "thelast"
  },

  
  {
    id: "thelast",
    component: (
      <div> {Sendemail()} </div>
    ),
  
    end: true
  },


  
];
```

THis code is my last try, on the last proposition, i just tried to put my function Sendmail()  in the id:"the last". But i can't call function in array. I am quite lost, how can i do that?

Thanks for yours answers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with Sendemail. But maybe this code will work

```
function SendEmail() 
{
   console.log('test')
   return null
}
// in steps
 {
id: "thelast",
component: (
  <SendEmail/>
),

end: true
}
```